# FPDF: euro symbol impossible. I have tried all the solutions

Tags: php, utf-8, fpdf

first of all, i know that this question has asked a lot here, but i have tried all the solutions and still not working. € symbol in my bills 
are translated by "?".

What have I tried?

Use iconv:

```
iconv("UTF-8", "ISO-8859-1//TRANSLIT", '€');
iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252', $yourtext);
//etc.
```

try to make a new font and load:

```
$pdf->AddFont('DejaVu','','DejaVuSansCondensed.ttf',true);
$pdf->AddFont('DejaVu', 'B', 'DejaVuSansCondensed-Bold.ttf', true);
//etc.
```

Defining the € character as constant and printing it

```
define('EURO',chr(128));
```

Using utf8_encode and decode functions, etc

Nothing, abutsutamente nothing has worked for me. And I'm surprised that some of these solutions have worked for other people

the other question is also about special characters. I have problem saving the pdf filename when this has accents

```
$pdf->Output('I',$number.'-'.$client.'.pdf');
```

windows save the file for example with "Ã" character

I'm using Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS with utf-8

thank you so much

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10626075/fpdf-and-special-characters

Comment: ISO 8859-1 predates the Euro. Try ISO 8859-15 instead.

Answer (score 1):

FPDF does not support multi-byte characters. You can use [tFPDF](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script92.php) (a derivate of FPDF). tFPDF uses the PHP multi-byte string functions and generates its output encoded in UTF-8. FPDF does not.

Answer (score 0):

I normally use `$pdf>TEXT(5,5,'Price: '.chr(164).' 5,00');`

and it will write the line **Price: € 5,00** in the created pdf.

**But it only works if the € sign is embedded in the used (generated) font file!**

And with the out of the box delivered 'verdana or arial' that isn't the case.
So lookup a nice .TTF font file (say opensans.ttf) and use
http://www.fpdf.org/makefont/make.php to generate the 2 needed new font-files that will contain the euro sign at location 164. Use on that page the ISO-8859-15 ecoding to generate files with the extended ascii range. The new generated font-files are named opensans.php and opensans.z Both need to be copied into the fonts dir of your webserver so that fpdf.php can use them. Now add the new font to the pdf generator by using:

```
$pdf->AddFont('opensans','','OpenSans-Regular.php'); //regular
$pdf->SetTextColor(0, 0, 100); //textcolor
$pdf->SetFont('opensans','','6'); //activefont
$pdf>Text(5,5,'Price: '.chr(164).' 5,00'); //text starting at 5,5
```

Done.

Answer (score 0):

I succeed with mix of technics :

```
strtr(iconv('UTF-8','CP1252',$value),[chr(128)=>chr(160)])
```

For info, fdf pdf encoding final function :

```
private function encode_fdf_field($value)
{
    return trim(addcslashes(strtr(iconv('UTF-8','CP1252',$value),[chr(128)=>chr(160)]),"\n\r\t\\()"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just have to encode the php file in **ANSI**
Then if you write € in a cell, it will display €, et voilà!